# firefox syntax error

Tags: php, javascript, firefox

i have a code like this .

in a line.php file:
        in simple speeking ,  i just output a string when query this page:

```
<?php
print("love you")
?>
```

then , in a b.php , i use the template code bellow (php template),i have code like this
   i will call the draw_line_chart function , this function will query line.php to get the        output .

```
function get_char(product,project){
    var lineUrl = 'line.php';
    send_http_request(lineUrl,_plot_line);

    function _plot_line(request){
    ;//plot_line(request,product,project) //function to get the line code .
    }
}


function send_http_request(url,call_function){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
        http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
        }
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
       try {
      http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
       } catch (e) {
      try {
    http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {}
       }
    }
    if (!http_request) {
        alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(http_request.readyState == 4){
       call_function(http_request);
  }
    }
    http_request.open('GET',url,false);
    http_request.send(null);
    return http_request;
}
```

ok, when it is used in google chrome , it's right , but when in firefox. it go's wrong . and in the error console , it say `syntax error "love you"`

Comment: where is the `plot_line` function/ Where does firefox says the error resides? it should give you an file+line reference

Comment: it dosen't matter what plot_line do, if i miss it , still wrong.

Comment: Also, it may be worth including a library such as jQuery or mootools for this sort of thing... both include robust and easy-to-use AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("love you");
```

you are missing the semi-colon at the end of the function.

Comment: it's not about the ; semi-colon